# Does fullscreen event trigger resize in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, layout, resize, fullscreen

I'm trying to set up a fullscreen toggle and implement elements of fluidity however am uncertain if I have to include a dispatch event in the toggle for screen resize or will this be something that will be detected by the previous eventListener when the fullscreen toggle is activated?

Furthermore having looked online for several days on the subject, I'm still uncertain where it's optimal to place the resize control of my stage elements.

```
public function Main():void {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeListener);
    stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE_ACCEPTED, fullScreenRedraw);
}

private function resizeListener (e:Event):void {

    // - Do I put my resize control options here to cater for general resize or see below?
myMovie.width = stage.stageWidth; // etc
}
private function fullScreen(e:MouseEvent):void {
    try {
    switch (stage.displayState) {
        case StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE:
            /* If already in full screen mode, switch to normal mode. */
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;

        break;
        default:
            stage.fullScreenSourceRect = null;
            // If not in full screen mode, switch to full screen mode.
            stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
        break;
        }
    } catch (err:SecurityError) {
        // ignore
    }
}
private function fullScreenRedraw(event:FullScreenEvent):void { 
    if ( event.fullScreen ) {
        // FULLSCREEN TRUE

        // - Or do I put my resize control options here to cater for the fullscreen as well?
        myMovie.width = stage.stageWidth; // etc

        var fScrField:TextField = new TextField();
        fScrField.y = 480;
        fScrField.text = "Redraw : True";
        addChild(fScrField);
    } else {
        // NON FULLSCREEN
        fScrField.text = "Redraw : False";
        addChild(fScrField);
    } 
}
```

**** Amended handlers as mentioned on adobe. But conflicting info on what goes where and why?!

```
private function activateHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("activateHandler: " + event);
}
private function fullScreenRedraw(event:FullScreenEvent):void { 
    if ( event.fullScreen ) {
        // Add additional panels if set/sizes 
        var fScrField:TextField = new TextField();
        fScrField.y = 480;
        fScrField.text = "Redraw : True";
        addChild(fScrField);
    } else {
        // Remove additional panels etc
        fScrField.text = "";
        fScrField.text = "Redraw : False";
        addChild(fScrField);
    } 
}
```

Now I've been able to get it working in all manner of ways using the code above with variations but having spent days online googling there seems to be no efficiant or clear explanation which is best.

Any help on where this could be better optimised and made more efficient as I've kind of just crowbar'd it together from what I can work out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-complicating it. Try that way:

```
// in your constructor:
fullScreenBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleFullScreen); 
stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, refreshStage); 
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, refreshStage);
// then handle stage resize:
private function refreshStage(event:Event = null):void
{
  if ( stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL ) {
    // handle stage in normal mode

  } else {
    // handle stage in full screen mode

  }
}
// handle stage state toggle:
private function toggleFullScreen(event:Event = null):void
{
  if ( stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL ) 
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
  else
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
}
```

Comment: You could well be right, I'll give it try. There's so many half explanations online it's hard to see through what's effective and what can be done for the sake of it.

The method I tried was to cover interactive keyboard use as explained in one method however it didn't seem to respond too well to actions once fullscreen, hence me playing around with it.

What I got was working and did it well but I just was unsure about all the options as to where you could also implement the changes and its then easy to get lost as I did.

I'll test it shortly as it certainly looks easier to grasp! Thanks.

Comment: Till I develop further my site I'll keep this available as an option but I'm still not happy about the resize/interactive resize options and need to test that out further before I commit either way, which is a personal issue I'm looking into with the resize/fullscreen issue.

Yours is clearly more simple in practice and works too but it's the sheer lack of right and wrong in flash which I hate and especially with the interactive options, there's little on what it actually does and how it helps, I just feel the best implementation should include it (somehow - being the question), but thanks.

Comment: I've only used interactive full screen in AIR apps (kiosk) when i needed textfields. Check this out, maybe you're missing some params: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS58a13becbbb904c7-28cf6d32136e60de784-8000.html

Comment: Hi Mika, I've managed to get it working I'm just not sure of the full implementation within flash, online there is a few examples which all vary quite a bit. The html setup is ok, I'm ok with that but in the as3 code there seems to be a number of ways I'm just trying to work out which is the best bulletproof implementation possible.

Comment: what bullets are you trying to proof?

Comment: The example I'm working on is a fluid layout with obvious resize options in the navigation and sections. The problem I noticed is that once the page had been made fullscreen the setup hadn't acknowledged the resize despite it being fullscreen, (larger or smaller) than before. It responds in fullscreen and only then would add the changes. I cheated and dispatched the event to trigger, it just seems a dirty way. The other problem was then looking into interactive layout with the (activateHandler) & (fullScreenRedraw) options!? I thought maybe assigned the resize options in the wrong place.

Comment: I've ammended the code subject to recommendations and info found through contributions on here but it gets deeper. Like I say, getting it working isn't my problem, I'm trying to get to the bottom of what makes for the correct procedure or if not the correct way, the most fluid and problem free way.